# Moving object animation in X and Y

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created animation for moving object in X, but how do I add also Y?

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
Pointer.RenderTransform = trans;
DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 500, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));
anim2.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
anim2.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2);
```

Comment: Put the animations in a Storyboard, rather than starting them manually.

Comment: Are you set on performing this task in code, or will XAML do? I ask because it's the only way I do it.

Comment: Only in code, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**StoryBoard**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add both animations as child:

```
Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard
                    { Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325)) };

DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 500, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));
anim2.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
anim2.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim2, trans);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 500, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));
anim1.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
anim1.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, trans);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

storyBoard.Children.Add(anim2);
storyBoard.Children.Add(anim1);

storyBoard.Begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an answer:

```
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        Pointer.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation animX = new DoubleAnimation(0, 750, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));
        DoubleAnimation animY = new DoubleAnimation(0, 100, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));

        animX.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
        animY.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };

        animX.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animX);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, animY);
```